# How to uncheck then check a checkbox on one click of another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I know this probably sounds wierd, but I have a situation where I move the handles of a range slider to filter stuff out.

When I release the click, I want it to uncheck the checkbox then check it. Toggle it off then on, in other words

**HTML**

The checkbox to toggle `.rangecheck`

```
<div class="checkbox range-button">
   <input type="checkbox" class="rangecheck" />
</div>
```

And the Object that will be clicked

```
<div class="noUI-handle"></div>
```

I'm thinking it will lok something like this:

```
jQuery('.noUi-handle').click(function() {
//code to toggle the checkbox
});
```

**Update**

just to clarify I'm trying to have a double click function. So when I click on `.noUi-handle` it double clicks the checkbox. (unchecks it then checks it back on) All in one click.

Comment: Why do you want to uncheck a button and then immediately check it again? Why not just leave it checked?

Comment: Yes like a double click. Can't leave it checked because there is flaw in my code so I have to find a workaround for the time being.

Comment: Have you tried `$('.rangecheck').trigger('dblclick');`?

Comment: Also, what's the flaw in your code that forces you to do this? Perhaps that's the better question.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LxLsQ/2/ ?

Comment: @Jack go here[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtree5757/suqqU/10/) The JS checks for changes, but I don't know how to incorporate the slider into the items to be checked. Kinda complicated,I'm not too good. Followed tut.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks, that seemed to be what I was after, but it didn't work in my case. Not sure why, but I guess it is time to do it the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Try this,

```
$('.noUI-handle').click(function () {
        $('.rangecheck').prop('checked', !$('.rangecheck').is(":checked") );
    });
```

Comment: Using `.is()` does a pretty inefficient search to find all elements that have checked property set to true.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, looking for a double click function. Uncheck then check only with one click.